# Question of Do Carmo's diff geo.

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there a simple closed curve in the plane with length equal to 6 feet and bound- in an area of 3 square feet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the curve $\gamma$ is a circle then the radius would be $r=\frac {6}{2 \pi}= \frac 3 \pi$, thus the area bounded by $\gamma$ would be $\pi r^2=\frac {3^2} \pi < 3$. Since the circle is the curve in the plane the maximizes the area of the bounded 2-ball for a fixed perimeter,  you cannot have any embedded $\mathbb{S^1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of length $6$ that bounds an area greater than $\frac{6^2}{2^2 \pi}$. (See also  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#The_isoperimetric_problem_in_the_plane
about the isoperimetric problem.)